# how to use Q_OBJECT MOC in android JNI

Tags: java, android, eclipse, qt

I'm newer in android programming, i just build qt 5.2 for android and using to my project. However, when inheritance OBject in my class and using the O_OBJECT marcro i get 'vtalble' error. After a long time of research I found that need to use qmake and .moc file to buile. But i cannot find how to use it in eclipse.

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QObject>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTime>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class myclass:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myclass (QObject *parent=0);
}
```

Is there any way I can integrate the Q_OBJECT macro in my android project or what flags i should add in android.mk?